# Nginx is sending proxy saved conent in gzip format

Tags: caching, nginx

I used config [given in this](http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2008/04/page-level-caching-with-nginx/) for page level caching of php content. The problem is that the cached page is saving in gzip format and it's returning the same gzip content to browser.

I need the o/p like this "12:15:37 12:15:47" (Its coming for 1st time when the page is not cached) after that if request is resend it is returning ‹������34²26±24à23Œ¸¸�`Î9”��� (gzip response as I tried zcat its returning fine)

**Response Headers**

```
Server nginx/0.8.34
Date Wed, 17 Mar 2010 07:04:58 GMT
Content-Type text/html
Last-Modified Wed, 17 Mar 2010 07:04:20 GMT
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Connection keep-alive
Vary Accept-Encoding
Expires Wed, 17 Mar 2010 07:04:58 GMT
Cache-Control max-age=0
Content-Encoding gzip
```

**Request Headers**

```
Host localhost
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.18) Gecko/2010021501 
Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.18 GTB6
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 300
Connection keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you missed adding the gzip_static option which will serve gzipped content correctly.

However, I have now posted a new article based on Nginx 0.7+ which is better for use as a proxy cache. It doesn't need that option anymore.

<s>http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2010/04/page-level-caching-with-nginx/</s>